# Assets path : absolute vs generated

Tags: c++, opengl, assets

I'm currently making a "fromAssets" function that provide a path to the assets folder where ever the program is execute.

The function come from the following part of code.

***Header file :***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

namespace path {
    static fs::path BUILD_PATH;
    const void initialiseBuildPath(const char *argv);
    const char * fromAssets(const char * path);
}
```

***Source file :***

```
using namespace path;

const void path::initialiseBuildPath(const char *argv0) {
    BUILD_PATH = fs::initial_path<fs::path>();
    BUILD_PATH = fs::system_complete(fs::path(argv0))
                            .parent_path()
                            .parent_path();
}

const char * path::fromAssets(const char * path) {
    std::string strPath = std::string(path);
    return (BUILD_PATH.string() + "/assets/" + strPath).c_str();
}
```

***Use :***

```
const char * absolute = "/Users/thomaspetillot/CLionProjects/glDiscoverProject/build/assets/shader/basic.vert.glsl";
const char * generated = path::fromAssets("shader/basic.vert.glsl");
cout << strcmp(absolute, generated) << endl; // show 0



// Work
auto * shader = new Shader(absolute,
                           path::fromAssets("shader/basic.frag.glsl"));

// Doesn't work
auto * shader = new Shader(generated,
                           path::fromAssets("shader/basic.frag.glsl"));
```

Folder structure :

```
build
├── assets
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── pepe.jpg
│   │   └── snoop.jpg
│   └── shader
│       ├── basic.frag.glsl
│       └── basic.vert.glsl
└── bin
    └── program
```

**How can it work for the frag shader but not for the other ?**

Comment: How should we know? What is the result of `path::fromAssets("shader/basic.vert.glsl")` and how is it different from `"/Users/a/b/c/build/assets/shader/basic.vert.glsl"`?

Comment: They're not different, strcmp return 0 - That's where the mystery comes from.

Comment: Ah, spotted the problem.

Comment: Can you lead me to the solution ? I've edit with the strcmp comparison.

Comment: See my answer. Chances are high that the strcmp comparison just works because there is absolutely no code inbetween (and thus nothing could override the freed memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fromAssets` method returns a pointer to an invalid memory address. That happens because you return the `c_str()` pointer of a std::string object that is a local variable of that function. When the function returns, all local variables, including the std::string, get deleted and the pointer returned points to a no longer existing memory address.

The best (and most modern) fix would be to return the std::string object itself instead of a const char* pointer. You can than either pass the c_str pointer to the Shader constructor or even better adjust the constructor to take `const std::string&` as parameters.